# Definition of genus of a Fano variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Sorry this question is quite easy.

What is the general definition of the genus of a smooth Fano variety?

I know that for Fano $3$-folds the genus is $g(X) =  \frac{(-K_{X})^3}{2} + 1$.

I have seen many authors use the notion of genus for (prime) Fano $n$-folds for $n \geq 4$ but I cannot find the definition after some searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was answered on by the user Pop on MO :

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/396985/formula-for-genus-of-a-fano-variety.

The answer is $$\frac{(n-2)(-K_{X})^n}{2}+1.$$